# Certificate issue when using serverless and serverless-domain-manager with custom domain

Tags: aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, serverless

I'm trying to set up a `custom domain` for my API Gateway and Lambda function.

I registered a domain with `route53`. Ex: `myDomainToTestApi.net`

I also created the certificates for: myDomainToTestApi.net, *.myDomainToTestApi.net, www.myDomainToTestApi.net

I installed the plugin `serverless-domain-manager` for `serverless framerwork`

In my `serverless.yml` I added (under **custom**):

```
 customDomain:
    domainName: myDomainToTestApi.net
    basePath: ''
    stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
    certificateName: '*.myDomainToTestApi.net'
    createRoute53Record: true
```

ALL resources are in `us-east-1`

When I run:

```
sls create-domain
```

I receive the following error...

```
Serverless: Load command test
Serverless: Load command dashboard
Serverless: Invoke create_domain
Serverless: [AWS apigateway 404 0.374s 0 retries] getDomainName({ domainName: 'myDomainToTestApi.net' })
Serverless Domain Manager: NotFoundException: Invalid domain name identifier specified
Serverless: [AWS acm 200 0.35s 0 retries] listCertificates({ CertificateStatuses: [ 'PENDING_VALIDATION', 'ISSUED', 'INACTIVE', [length]: 3 ] })

  Error --------------------------------------------------

  Error: Error: Could not find the certificate *.myDomainToTestApi.net.
      at ServerlessCustomDomain.<anonymous> (/Users/user/project/node_modules/serverless-domain-manager/dist/index.js:279:23)
```

If I go to the Certificate Manager view, the status for all is `Issued`

Anyone knows what could be happening...? Thanks.

Comment: I'm getting the same error, did you manage to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Try to add another propertie called `certificateArn`, you can find `certicateArn` in the certificate manager detailed view of the domain

```
certificateArn: 'xxxxx'
```

[image]

Comment: I added the `arn`. Still failing but with new `error`: Serverless: Load command dashboard
Serverless: Invoke create_domain
Serverless: [AWS apigateway undefined 9.234s 0 retries] getDomainName({ domainName: 'myDomainToTestApi.net' })
`Serverless Domain Manager: CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config`
 
  Error --------------------------------------------------
 
  Error: Error: Unable to fetch information about myDomainToTestApi.net

Btw, I do have my AWS credentials in `/.aws/credentials`

Comment: And then another cryptic error appears... `UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'securityPolicy' found in params` even though I did not specify it myself (uses the default)

Answer (score 0):

It is actually

```
sls create_domain
```

(notice the underscore)

Comment: @AnkurLoriya sorry mate but this is the correct command...
here are the docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-domain-manager